# UI not rendered properly after building VueJS 2 for production

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, bulma

when I run VueJS 2 with Bulma with Webpack locally, the UI renders fine. However, after building my site for production (npm run build), the UI layout goes off. Does anyone know what went wrong with the build process?

This is a screenshot of vue running without building for production: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0vqD.jpg

This is a screenshot of vue running after building for production: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fulrE.jpg

Comment: Nobody can be able to help you with this much information. Did you check if CSS is proper(after build) ?

Comment: @Pradeepb Hi, how do you check if the CSS is proper after the build? Because if i run my project locally (npm run dev), the UI looks the way i want. However, after building it for my site for production (npm run build), the UI screws up somehow...

Comment: check using browser debugger??